# How can i change Container color with GestureDetector and RiverPod

Tags: flutter

i need to change the color of the container on tap using RiverPod and GestureDetector, the class must extends StatelessWidget , I saw many similar questions but did not find an answer , thanks in advance

page class

```
                         child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  type == home;
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: type == home
                                        ? theme.colorScheme.primaryVariant
                                        : Colors.transparent,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
```

state class

```
class NewTasksNotifier extends StateNotifier<NewTasksState> {
  NewTasksNotifier(this.newTasksState) : super(const NewTasksState());

  final NewTasksState newTasksState;

  void setType() {
    if (state.type == work) return;
    state = state.copyWith(
      type: work,
    );

    if (state.type == home) return;
    state = state.copyWith(
      type: home,
    );
  }
}



final newTasksProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<NewTasksNotifier, NewTasksState>(
  (ref) => NewTasksNotifier(
    ref.watch(newTasksProvider),
  ),
);
```

NewTasksState class

```
import 'package:freezed_annotation/freezed_annotation.dart';

part 'new_tasks_state.freezed.dart';

const String work = '1';
const String home = '2';

@freezed
class NewTasksState with _$NewTasksState {
  const factory NewTasksState({
    String? error,
    @Default(false) bool isLoading,
    @Default(work) String type,
  }) = _NewTasksState;
}
```

type variable in page class

```
  final type = watch(newTasksProvider).type;
```

Comment: can you add `NewTasksState`

Comment: added NewTasksState

Comment: can you add more about body snippet. like how you are getting `type`

Comment: done , added type variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solve it this way:

```
class NewTasksNotifier extends StateNotifier<NewTasksState> {
  NewTasksNotifier() : super(NewTasksState(type: "work"));

  void setType() {
    if (state.type == "work")
      state = state.copyWith(
        type: "home",
      );
    else
      state = state.copyWith(
        type: "work",
      );
  }
}

final newTasksProvider =
    StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<NewTasksNotifier, NewTasksState>(
        (ref) => NewTasksNotifier());
```

widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hooks_riverpod/hooks_riverpod.dart';

import 'new_tasks_state.dart';

class ColorCOntainer extends StatelessWidget {
  const ColorCOntainer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Consumer(
            builder: (context, watch, child) {
              final type = watch(newTasksProvider);

              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  print("tapped ${type.type}");

                  context.read(newTasksProvider.notifier).setType();
                },
                child: Container(
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color:
                        type.type == "home" ? Colors.pink : Colors.cyanAccent,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                  ),
                  child: Center(child: Text("btn")),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call a method on the `StateNotifier` like this:

```
context.read(newTasksProvider.notifier).setType()
```

You should edit the method `setType` accordingly with what you want to achieve. Do you want to toggle the type? Maybe rename it to `toggleType` and implement the toggle.

Full `GestureDetector`:

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: context.read(newTasksProvider.notifier).setType,
    child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: type == home
            ? theme.colorScheme.primaryVariant
            : Colors.transparent,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: There are only two such containers for the entire application, the type and home variables are designed to choose between one option, that is, when choosing one option, the second cannot be selected